# Where to put the common word in a series including symbols

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

> Look out for bold **D**, struck-through <s>D</s> and italic *D* formatting.
>
> Look out for bold **D**, struck-through <s>D</s> and italic formatting *D*.

Which of these above sentences should I be using?

The sentences show a series of three terms with the word they have in common (`formatting`) taken out of the series and placed at the end. My question is, how symbols should be positioned when they are added as an example for each term - where to place the **D**, the <s>D</s> and the *D* - especially around this common word.

A sentence without these symbols included is unambiguous and issue-free:

> Look out for bold, struck-through and italic formatting.

So, when adding symbols in the sentence to illustrate what is being talked about - as is often done in mathematical contexts and scientific texts - how should they be placed in a sentence with a series of terms?

Comment: Stylistically,  I would use: **Look out for uppercase letters such as A, B, C and lowercase ones such as a, b, c.**

Comment: @Lambie Is my sentence structure not possible? Imagine having many (more than two) terms in the series. The `such as` structure you suggest would quickly make a sentence quite long.

Comment: Look out for uppercase letters (such as A, B and C) and lowercase ones (such as a, b, and c). You do not ***need*** etc. Such as implies all the things that would fit. etc. is redundant here.

Comment: Your very first sentence is ok, but it would then only apply to those letters and no others. That's the problem.

Comment: The word  "letters" is redundant; upper case and lower case apply only to letters. If your readership does not understand that A,B,C are upper case and a,b,c, are lower case, you need an extra sentence to explain that. Then tell them that they must "look out" for them (whatever that means).

Comment: @JeremyC Thank you for pointing out that issue. I tried my best to find a fitting example to illustrate my question - the issue you point out here is not the point of the question.

Comment: Then I do not understand the point of your question. If I am not alone, it would be helpful for you to say more.

Comment: @JeremyC The point of the question is how to structure such a sentence.

Comment: @Lambie and JeremyC. The question is now updated with a new example to emphasize the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to add symbols to a sentence like:

Look out for bold, struck-through and italic formatting.

With symbols:

```
Look out for bold (**D**), struck-through (D) and italic (*D*) formatting.
```

I cannot reproduce the struck-through letter, sorry.

In this example, the letters can be placed right after what they are, as there is only a single short letter.

Please note: when you say look out for, I wonder if you mean: Make to check?

The main point I would make here is that the style should be adhered to throughout your text.

But this one can also be used to match the other one:

```
Look out for uppercase letters (A, B, C) and lowercase ones (a, b, c).
```

**Now the two examples are in the same style with the least amount of extra "stuff"**.